# No access to portal

Tags: c#

I am trying to add a "Customer Community Plus User" profile user with the Salesforce .Net api. I have not done any configuration changes to this profile.

```
//Try to add user with a contact
Salesforce.Common.Models.SuccessResponse responseMsg = await client.CreateAsync("User", user);
```

I manage to add other profile types such as Chatter Free users via the api. But here I am getting "No access to portal" error. What is this issue? Do I need to do any configuration changes in the Salesforce portal for this profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Customer Community Plus User is not similar to other profiles .

These users are Contact records within salesforce who can access a Portal or community .To create these Users you need to have atleast a Portal or community(Its some set up inside your salesforce ) which has access to the Profile you are trying to assign .

The key thing will be you will need a Contact record Id from the salesforce before you create these users .You will link user.ContactId = ContactId (Contact record Id will be mapped to the Users COntactId).

Also another key things to consider will be

> The Account linked to the contact has a owner field and owner needs to have a valid role to allow you to create the User .

Comment: Thanks,have a different question which I guess relates to this one. Is this the same reason that this license type/profile types not available in Salesforce Set Up->Manage User-> New User UI. Do you know what is the criteria used to load license types+profiles in the Add New User UI in Salesforce? Because I am developing a web app to add users via the api. Currently I display all license types available for the user. It seems like I need to restrict the license types I am displaying. Now sure whats the filter I need to use there.

Comment: Yes it really makes sense to restrict these.It requires a community set up